# Objective C: Finding all classes

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to find all classes participating in the given application, or under the same namespace?

Answer (score 4):

The runtime function `objc_getClassList()` will list all classes registered for the program. Objective-C doesn't have namespaces. (Just as a note for anyone reading: This is just about never something you should want to do.)

Comment: Yeah -- enumerating the classes is a really bad idea.  It'll cause a classes to be `+initialize`d, which may either bloat your app or cause mysterious crashes when you don't happen to touch the classes in the "right" order (that can't be known).